# Run a PowerShell script in C# that requires sign in

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way to connect to O365/Azure to change users licenses. I have a PowerShell script I typically use, and connect to it using

```
connect-azure ad
```

then it would prompt me for credentials and then it would go and assign the license or un-assign them. I am pretty much wanting to be able to do the same thing in C#. My first thought would be to have it run a PowerShell script however it throws an error

```
The 'Connect-AzureAD' command was found in the module 'AzureAD', but the module could not be loaded.
For more information, run 'Import-Module AzureAD'
```

I tried to install it during the script however that didn't work. Long story short, does anyone have any idea how I could connect to Azure to modify users O365 license in my C# utility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew as soon as I asked I would figure it out,
I had to force the import and then connect and then run the script!!

```
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Import-Module AzureAD -Force;");
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Connect-AzureAD");
```